# html onclick not happening when parameter has special characters like $ or

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a code in which I have three rows with three parameters $COKE, COKE, COKE.
Every row has a sublist which opens when I click the parameters. It works fine when parameter doesnt have any special characters i.e.

For case when $COKE is parameter it doesn't open sublist onclick. ($ dollar sign)
For case when COKE is parameter it opens sublist onclick.
For case when COKE. is parameter it doesn't open sublist onclick. (. dot sign)

```
data[i].parameter="$COKE"   
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "<tr id="+data[i].parameter+" onclick='showSublist(this.id)'>
```

data[i].paramater can have values as shown below $COKE, COKE.,COKE as an example.
Image shown as reference, where only case 2 opens but case 1 and case 3 doesn't open when I click them.

Cases Image [image]

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I couldn't share as its part of big code, but I think I got my answer, i.e. es the text escapeText solved the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By not escaping special characters you are creating invalid HTML code, that's why onclick doesn't work.

Here is example how browser handles special characters:

```js
function escape(a) {
  return "&#" + a.charCodeAt(0) + ";";
}

function escapeText(text) {
  return text.replace(/["'&<>]/g, escape);
}

function showSublist(id) {
  alert(id);
}
var data = [{
    parameter: "test"
  },
  {
    parameter: "$test"
  },
  {
    parameter: "<test"
  },
  {
    parameter: "test>"
  },
  {
    parameter: "<test>"
  },
  {
    parameter: '"test'
  },
  {
    parameter: 'test"'
  },
  {
    parameter: '"test"'
  },
  {
    parameter: "test."
  },
  {
    parameter: '&test'
  },
  {
    parameter: '&test;'
  },
  {
    parameter: "test${test}"
  },
];


for (let i = 0, tr = document.createElement("tr"); i < data.length; i++) {
  tr = tr.cloneNode(false);

  tr.innerHTML = '<td class="n">' + i + '</td>';

  /* original, incorrect structure */
  tr.innerHTML += "<td id=" + data[i].parameter + " onclick='showSublist(this.id)'>" + data[i].parameter + '</td>';

  tr.innerHTML += '<td class="n">' + i + '</td>';

  /* correct structure, no filter */
  tr.innerHTML += '<td id="' + data[i].parameter + '" onclick="showSublist(this.id)">' + data[i].parameter + '</td>';

  tr.innerHTML += '<td class="n">' + i + '</td>';

  /* correct structure, filter */
  tr.innerHTML += '<td id="' + escapeText(data[i].parameter) + '" onclick="showSublist(this.id)">' + escapeText(data[i].parameter) + '</td>';

  tr.onmouseover = mouseOver;
  document.getElementById("results").appendChild(tr);

};

var div = document.getElementById("html");

function mouseOver(e) {
  html.textContent = e.target.className == "n" ? e.target.nextSibling.outerHTML : e.target.outerHTML;
}
```

```css
th {
  text-align: start;
}

td:nth-child(even) {
  border-right: 1em solid transparent;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}
```

```html
<table id="results">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">
      Original, no quotes
    </th>
    <th colspan="2">
      Unescaped
    </th>
    <th colspan="2">
      Escaped
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="html"></div>
```

Comment: `$` isn't a special character though.

Comment: "Well, without seeing your code, how could anyone answer?" — Why did you try then? And don't confuse me with eiffeldreams.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were the one who posted the question...

Comment: Thanks @vanowm You're right. I didn't add escape text. It is working fine for me. Thankyou very much.